# Making a beamer section appear conditionally in TOC (on specific slide)?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, conditionals

In my slides, I've put extra material not part of the presentation itself, but which is useful in case someone is interested, into its own section called "Extra Material". Hence I don't want this section to appear in the ToC that is shown at the beginning of each section. However, I do want it to be shown in the ToC at the beginning of its own section.

See MWE below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{A}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]

  ``Extra Material'' \emph{shall not} appear here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{B}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{C}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Extra Material}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]

  ``Extra Material'' \emph{shall} appear here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this without having to make a handwritten ToC frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify which sections should be shown in the toc using `\tableofcontents[currentsection,sections=1-3]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{A}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,sections=1-3]

  ``Extra Material'' \emph{shall not} appear here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{B}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{C}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Extra Material}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]

  ``Extra Material'' \emph{shall} appear here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, it was as simple as that, and was even written in the Beamer manual. That'll teach me to RTFM more carefully next time...